# jquery appendTo and detach in order to replay animated gif

Tags: javascript, jquery, appendto, detach

This is my js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $lrgBanner = $('#panel');
    $lrgBanner.detach();

    $('#banner img').click(function () {
        $lrgBanner.appendTo('#ad').show();
        $('#banner').hide();
        console.log('banner was clicked');
    });

});

$('#close img').click(function () {
    $('#banner').show();
    $lrgBanner.detach();
    console.log('close was clicked');
});
```

And the HTML:

```
 <div id='ad'>

    <div id='banner'>
        <img src="img/hp-small.gif" alt="banner advertisement" />
    </div>

    <div id='panel'>
        <div id='background'>
            <img src="img/hp-large.gif" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div id='close'>
            <img src="img/btn_close.gif" alt="close" />
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

The div #background contains an animated gif. I was told that using detach and appendTo would restart the gif content, but it doesn't seem to be working.

I wondered about trying to use a load function (or an unload on the #close img click function.

Does anyone have any advice?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: Sorry I have made a v5 of that fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Gm7jt/5/

Comment: I've updated answer, works in jsfiddle on chrome. Not tested other browsers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should reset src attribute of animated gif instead:

[SEE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Gm7jt/6/)

Note that you shouldn't set variables as global if you don't need to access it from global scope.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     gifAnimated = $('#background img')[0],
     gifSrc = "http://mlkshk.com/r/R245.gif";
     $lrgBanner = $('#panel');
     $lrgBanner.detach();

     $('#banner img').click(function () {
         gifAnimated.src = gifSrc;
         $lrgBanner.appendTo('#ad').show();
         $('#banner').hide();
         console.log('banner was clicked');
     });

 });

 $('#close img').click(function () {
     $('#banner').show();
     $lrgBanner.detach();
     gifAnimated.src = "";
     console.log('close was clicked');
 });
```

Comment: Yes that is working (I was tweaking it when you posted) although it is throwing an error in the console. But I think I can fix that. Thank you very much.

Comment: If you are talking about this error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parent' of null "  it's relative to jsfiddle, not code

Comment: Hehe, funnily enough jsfiddle isn't throwing an error, but my local version of the code was. Thank you, it's working though which is the main thing.